# Unknown module(s) in Qt

Tags: qt, qt5, qt3d

Unknown module(s) in Qt: 3-d. As I know, Qt(5.6) already have 3-D library, why still appear this reminder when I use it in Qt? Thanks very much.

Comment: can you include an abstracted code snippet that you are using that generates the error and also the verbose error itself?

Comment: add the relevant part of your .pro file(s), in particular the `QT +=` lines

Answer (score 2):

Because `3-d` isn't a `Qt` module, the correct modules are listed on the `Qt3D` page though: [Qt3D Docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-index.html).

They are: `QT += 3dcore 3drender 3dinput 3dlogic`