# Unknown module(s) in Qt: 3danimation

Tags: qt, qmake, qt3d

I am a beginner in Qt and wanted to learn about 3D rendering in Qt. The first thing the official document http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-index.html stated was to add the following line to its qmake .pro file:

```
QT += 3dcore 3drender 3dinput 3dlogic 3dextras 3danimation
```

However, running qmake after adding this line gave me an unknown module error:3danimation. I read this previous posted question [Unknown module(s) in QT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36125777/unknown-modules-in-qt). The solution stated to use

```
QT += 3dcore 3drender 3dinput 3dlogic
```

This solution worked for me but I have also read that `3danimation` contains various important classes from the Qt3DAnimation module. My question is that why following the official documentation gave me this error. Did I miss something. This question may sound very nooby, but I would appreciate if someone could explain this to me. Thanks in advance. BTW, I am using Qt creator 4.2.0 (based on Qt 5.7.1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Qt5 documentation follows the latest release which is Qt 5.10 at the moment and you are using older release (5.7).

If you take a look at archived [Qt3D in Qt 5.7](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.7/qt3d-index.html) documentation you can see that 3danimation is not mentioned there. According to this [blog post](http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/05/24/qt3d/) the technology preview of the Qt3D Animation module was released first time as part of Qt 5.9.

You should move to a newer release if you want to use Qt3D Animation. I would recommend Qt 5.9 which is LTS (long time support) release. At the moment, [Qt 5.9.5](https://blog.qt.io/blog/2018/04/12/qt-5-9-5-released/) is the newest version.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now that you have mentioned it, I feel like a noob for not checking the proper document for the particular version. Also I didn't knew that new version of Qt with LTS is released. I guess you learn new things everyday. Thanks for the info.